# How to invoke a MethodInfo from a Dictionary without having the original method type?

Tags: c#, dictionary, methods

I'm working on a project that takes user defined methods and uses them to interact with some data.

Right now, I have something like this:

(Main)

```
 ...
 string dllFile = @"C:\Path\GenericTester" + commandValue + ".dll";
 var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(dllFile);

 var type = assembly.GetType("DllNamespace.DllClass");

 string methodName = "FunctionForProperty" + commandValue; //commandValue is a string of a number

 var method = type.GetMethod(methodName);

 PropertiesDictionary.updateValue(int.Parse(commandValue), method);
 ...
```

On the `PropertiesDictionary` class:

```
static public class PropertiesDictionary
{
   public static Dictionary<int, MethodInfo> PropertiesMethods = new Dictionary<int, MethodInfo>();
                                                       
   public static void updateValue(int propertyId, MethodInfo method)
   {
      PropertiesMethods[propertyId] = method;
   }

   public static MethodInfo doFunctionForProperty(int propertyId)
   {                                         
      if (PropertiesMethods.ContainsKey(propertyId))
             return PropertiesMethods[propertyId];
      else
             return null;
   }
        
}
```

So, I'm trying to do something like this:

```
 MethodInfo method = ProjectNamespace.PropertiesDictionary.doFunctionForProperty(PropertyId);
 var result = method.Invoke(null, new object[] { ParametersOfTheFunctionOfTheDll });
 return result;
```

By the time I call that last lines I will no longer have access to the DLL (because we want in a future to just pass compiled code as `System.Reflection.Assembly Load(byte[])` and we will access to that information just once)

The problem is obviously that I'm not passing the object target to the `method.Invoke()`, like `var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);`, but I think I don't know what type I should be pointing to.

Is there maybe a cleaner way to achieve what I want? Like, passing the whole method to the Dictionary from a class in `System.Reflection.Assembly Load(byte[])` and not just the MethodInfo, so I can invoke it wherever I want without having to pass the target?

Comment: What do you mean by *"original method type"*? Do all the methods have the same signature?

Comment: By "original method type" I mean the class in which the method was originaly declarated by the user. I would like to invoke the method just having the information stored in the Dictionary, without having to point again to the Reflection.Assembly.
And nop, each method has a different generic signature (Like "Property"+PropertyId).

Comment: The first part is easy: `MemberInfo` (from which `MethodInfo` derives via `MethodBase`) has a property called `DeclaringType`.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this problem by setting the user defined methods as static, so I don't have to pass the target anymore. However I think this isn't the best solution, but for now it works for me.